# Standalone python terminal app

Tags: python

I have a simple python scripts which imports some functions and performs simple tasks based on user inputs via the python shell.

I would like to distribute this to users who do not have python installed or the same modules I have on my local machine.

I've looked at py2app but this seems to require a GUI or similar and I do not need this, only command line arguments etc.. My script used raw_import for receiving commands as below...

```
import time, sys, os

def main():

    name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
    print name

    time.sleep(60)
    print 'bye'
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

would anyone know the correct way to do this..

Comment: http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: which operating system do you use? same questions for your users?

Comment: sorry its OSX not windows

Answer (score 1):

Python is installed by default on OSX (and has been since at the very least 10.3). If your scripts are simple command-line affairs with no external dependencies, you don't have to do anything, just ship them.

If your script has dependencies, you need to write a proper `setup.py` for it, so that users may install it and its dependencies with one simple line (`python setup.py install`).

At that point, it means you want to read an introduction to Python packaging: http://guide.python-distribute.org/index.html

Comment: arr, ok but I have several modules which I import, how would I allow for this..?

Comment: What modules are those? Things you wrote yourself? In that case, why not ship a zip file?